# finding properties of struct stored in std::list c++

Tags: c++, struct, find, std, stdlist

I'm trying to fetch some data from a pre-defined list.

I have the following struct:

```
struct FileId
{
   int id; 
   std::string fileName;
   bool isValid;
};
```

I'm creating the following list:

```
std::list<FileId> filesList;

FileId newFileId;
newFileId.id = 1;
newFileId.fileName = somefile1;
newFileId.isValid = true;

FileId newFileId;
newFileId.id = 2;
newFileId.fileName = somefile2;
newFileId.isValid = false;
```

I'm trying, for example, to find a file by `id`, or all the files which are not valid, can it be done without looping the list with an iterator?

Comment: Implement `operator==` for `FileID` and use `std::find` defined in the `algorithm` library

Comment: If you want to search a file by id, then a better data structure would be a map<id,Field> and a map<Field, bool> (for validity checking) rather than a list. With a list, you will have to iterate over all elements sequentially either yourself, or through a library algorithm

Comment: I want to get the entire struct, and not only the `id/isValid` - I'm also about to expand the struct with more variables. Therefore I can't use map.

Comment: @IdanIsrael Will you want to look up by *any* (or a significant subset) of `FileId`'s members?

Comment: @BoBTFish Nope, Just by `id` and/or `isValid`.

Comment: Just use `std::find_if` with a suitable functor.

Comment: @IdanIsrael: Why does that fact prohibit using a map?

Comment: @IdanIsrael If `FileId` is large, you can still use a map like `map<id, FileID*>` or `map<id, std::unique_ptr<FileId> >` or `map<id, FileId::iterator>`. So data are stored in a list and maps are only used for lookup. Pointers / iterators are preserved when manipulating a list. However, the map key should not change, so you can do this for `id` but probably not for `isValid`. For the latter you'd still need to iterate.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `map<id, list<FileId>::iterator>` above.